# How to add static blocks to transactional emails?

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, transactional-mail

I have been looking around on how to add a static block into the transactional emails.

I found the solution on github here:  https://gist.github.com/mkdizajn/6351957

The regular way to add a static block to a CMS page is:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="this_block"}}
```

This does not work in transactional emails.

The github solution on the other hand:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="this_block" template="cms/content.phtml"}}
```

This works.

Why does it work?  And is this a good way to add static blocks to transactional emails?

Comment: for the emails i guess you want to set the email variables. So better assign the static block to variable and pass it to your email template.

Comment: I needed to allow `cms/block` under System -> Permissions -> blocks